# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs' while upgrading to Gradle 7.x

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-3.0

I am following the doc to update the react-native architecture to the new turbo and fabric. I upgraded Gradle to 7. I am facing the following issue. Please help.
[link to error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LNpK.png)
[link to tried solution but it didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zms7z.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on react-native. I got the same error when I enabled new architecture, which I resolved by making changes to the android/app/build.gradle by adding the following code

```
android {
   ......other code

   packagingOptions {
      pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libbutter.so'
   }
}
```

you might get other path errors with different architecture like 'lib/x86/libyoga.s' which you can include as above pickFirst'lib/x86/libyoga.s' in the next line. Clean and rebuild. I got the reference from https://github.com/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg/issues/227